# Remove new line from output

Tags: python

I have the below function:

```
i = 1
h_ = 4
for i in range(h_+1):
    w_i = " " * (h_ - i)
    h_i = "*" * i
    pyramid =  w_i + h_i
    print(pyramid)
i+1
```

Actual output:

```
$ python test.py

   *
  **
 ***
****
```

Expected output:

```
$ python test.py
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

How do I remove the new line at the beginning of the output?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make a small change in your for loop as below,

```
i = 1
h_ = 4
for i in range(1, h_+1):
    w_i = " " * (h_ - i)
    h_i = "*" * i
    pyramid =  w_i + h_i
    print(pyramid)
```

start the for loop with 1.